# rollback to SAVEPOINT

Tags: mysql, rollback

I was trying below statements in phpmyadmin. Database: mysql.

```
INSERT into cust values(5,'srk'); 
commit; 
UPDATE cust set cname='sk' where cid=5; 
savepoint A;
```

These statements are executed successfully.

But when i execute

```
rollback to A;
```

Error:

> `#1305 - SAVEPOINT A does not exist`

error is coming.

If i execute only rollback;
It executes successfully but result is actually not rolled back.

Comment: please kindly answer above question ASAP.

Comment: Have you fresh backups? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you weren't even in a transaction.  And even once in one for a `rollback to a savepoint`, you have to commit to make it seen. You simply have to play with it. This should help I hope.

One starts a transaction with `start transaction;`

```
create table cust
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    theValue int not null,
    theText varchar(50) not null,
    cname varchar(50) not null,
    cid int not null
);

INSERT into cust (theValue,theText,cname,cid) values(111,'aaa','a',1); 


start transaction;
    savepoint B1;
    INSERT into cust (theValue,theText,cname,cid) values(666,'aaa','a',1); 
    savepoint B2;
    INSERT into cust (theValue,theText,cname,cid) values(777,'aaa','a',1); 
    ROLLBACK to B2;
    -- at this moment, this connection can see 2 rows, other connections see 1 (id=1)
    select * from cust; -- visible to you but not others, that is,
commit;
-- at this moment all connections can see 2 rows. Give it a try with another connection open
```

.

```
select * from cust;
+----+----------+---------+-------+-----+
| id | theValue | theText | cname | cid |
+----+----------+---------+-------+-----+
|  1 |      111 | aaa     | a     |   1 |
|  2 |      666 | aaa     | a     |   1 |
+----+----------+---------+-------+-----+
```

From the Manual page [SAVEPOINT, ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT, and RELEASE SAVEPOINT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/savepoint.html)

> The ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT statement rolls back a transaction to the
>   named savepoint without terminating the transaction.

---

It is important to know that in your code, line 2, the `commit`, you were never in a transaction. You never started one. There was nothing to `commit`.

Your line 1, the insert, considering it is not in a transaction, is a mini implicit transaction. It just happens. When your line 2 came around, the server was thinking, commit what?

Answer (score 0):

You must have to set,

set autocommit=0;

[image: screenshot]